# Firebase Index Issue when field name has spaces

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

[image]

When I try to add a firebase index for my flutter app, it shows this error. I have a field with the name 'Date Added' with a space in between. When I try to add 'DateAdded' as an index it works, but my field name has a space in it. Is there a way to add an index where the field name has a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding Indexes with a field name that has a space in between, you should escape it with `backticks`. It should be like this:

```
`Date Added`
```

See screenshot below:
[image]
Result:
[image]